# Django EmailMultiAlternatives sending to multiple "to" addresses

Tags: python, django, email, django-email

Is there a way in Django EmailMultiAlternatives that you can send to multiple "to" addresses, without having to send it again?

Have tried separating the email int the tuple by commas, but only the first recipient receives the emails.

Comment: Have you also checked that the other recipients are valid e-mail addresses (no typos, not in the spam folder, etc)?

Answer (score 11):

A list of email addresses should work, as [the example in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/?from=olddocs#sending-alternative-content-types) shows.

```
to_emails = ['alice@example.com', 'bob@example.com']
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, to_emails)
```

You might want to use `bcc` instead of `to_emails` to prevent users from seeing the other recipients of the email.

```
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, bcc=to_emails)
```

Comment: can we pass a set or tupple as to to_emails?

Comment: @user570826 It's easy to test it yourself and see if it works! A tuple will certainly work. A set is iterable, so I imagine it would work as well.

Comment: Just a heads up if you're sending to multiple recipients using this method - all recipients will be listed in the "To" field (so that recipients will be able to see the other recipient).

If you want to keep the identities of other recipients secret, you'll need to iterate over each destination address and call `send_mail` once for each recipient.

Comment: @GavinBallard good point, I've added a note about using `bcc` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a for loop. I'm also using this to filter which users emails are sent to.

```
for user in users:
    if user.is_active and user != request.user and user.last_login != None:
        message = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        subject = "your subject here",
            from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            to = [user.email],
            )
        context = {'request':request, 'user':user, 'event':event}
        html_template = get_template("notifications/new_event_email.html").render(context)
        message.attach_alternative(html_template, "text/html")
        message.send()
```

It might not be the best way, but it's working for me.